# How to change dplyr::tbl connection encoding to utf8?

Tags: r, dplyr, rmysql

In a MySQL database, a table is encoded in utf8, but for some reason the connection is in latin1.

```
res <- RMySQL::dbSendQuery(con,"show variables like 'character_set_%'")
dbFetch(res)
           Variable_name                      Value
1     character_set_client                     latin1
2 character_set_connection                     latin1
3   character_set_database                    utf8mb4
4 character_set_filesystem                     binary
5    character_set_results                     latin1
6     character_set_server                     latin1
7     character_set_system                       utf8
8       character_sets_dir /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

[This page explain how to set the connection's character set to utf8 using RMySQL](https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL/issues/2).

```
RMySQL::dbGetQuery(con,"show variables like 'character_set_%'")
RMySQL::dbGetQuery(con,"set names utf8")
```

But I actually prefer to use the `dplyr::tbl` to query the database. Since the connection created by `dplyr::src_mysql` only has the possibility to send sql statements that create tables. What is the dplyr way to set the connection setting to use utf8 encoding?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934752/utf-8-encoding-with-dplyr-and-sqlite

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I have seen it thank you, I also convert character columns to utf8 using an ad-hoc solution with `iconv()` but it is a hack and I would rather read character vectors directly in utf8. Especially because the database is already in utf8.

Comment: I feel your pain. Encoding is a bane for everyone working with non-latin1 data.

Comment: I actually fixed this by changing the database server configuration settings to utf8, and choosing the option `skip-character-set-client` in /etc/mysql/my.cf

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, which I solved as follows:

```
foo_db <- src_mysql(host='0.0.0.0',user='dbuser',password='a_password',
                    dbname='FlightTimes',port=3336)
dbGetQuery(foo_db$con,'SET NAMES utf8')
```

I found this was possible by looking at the structure of `foo_db` via `str(foo_db)`, seeing there was a `con` attribute of class `MySQLConnection`, then applying your `dbGetQuery` mantra.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the server option file (located in /etc/mysql/my.cnf on a Debian system) and add the following options:

```
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

The mysql server configuration file can also be edited with mysql-workbench.

After this change, `dplyr::tbl` fetches character vector encoded in utf-8.